# Question closed as duplicate of a similar one

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

I just posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/924449/is-there-a-way-to-selectively-enable-font-smoothing-in-windows) about enabling font smoothing for *select* applications, and it got closed as a dupe of a [problem with quick switching](https://superuser.com/questions/297455/toggle-cleartype-windows-7) for *all* applications. I understand it must have been an oversight, so I ask to unmark it as exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's been re-opened by the community you can close this question now.

Comment: How do I do that? And should I really?

Comment: Normally you just accept an answer and the question's closed. Although perhaps only a mod can add the status-completed tag to your question above.

Comment: Yea those tags are restricted to moderators. I have no option to instantly close it.